# Circular Brush Metal

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to create this circular brush metal texture using the noise node(procedural) in blender 2.8 ?[image: Like this]

Comment: I could not get exactly that result, but I got a good way with a very basic Waves Texture Node set to Rings with a Texture Mapping Node to position the center of the rings. Then changing the Scale and plugging the results into the Metal and Roughness of the Principled BSDF Shader. I think you need a nice HDR to get the reflection right. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The Principled BSDF has `anisotropic` and `anisotropic rotation` settngs in order to achieve this.

[This video](https://youtu.be/4H5W6C_Mbck?t=1257) explains pretty well how it works.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4MTnpnahu0

I Think you're looking for an anisotropic metal shader

Comment: Hi. Please read [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)